Why Are There Visible Edges In My Render?

This is how my scene renders in Cycles, regardless of whether I use GPU or CPU. Notice that many edges are visible, but some are light-colored and some are dark colored.
I recently retopologized this mesh by hand and deleted the high poly mesh from this version of the file. I also UV unwrapped it and have been trying to texture paint it, although weird things have been happening... Going to render, or other mode changes (it's hard to track because I never expect it to happen) causes the texture files to reset or lose my painting data, despite my having saved them individually (all files exist in my folder but have almost nothing on them beyond what they started with at creation).
Another weird thing is that when I try to add a subdivision surface modifier (this was originally just an experiment), it looks like there are two meshes on top of one another:

I noticed that the areas that look strange in the render are the same areas that look doubled with the modifier on. Also, raising/lowering the Levels Viewport of the modifier causes no visible change to the topology, and turning the cage on causes the mesh to look normal.
Someone suggested that it could be the previous mesh turned off in the viewport but not the render, and as you can see in the above scene, everything is on. But just to confirm this, I turned the LoResHead off in the render, which produced this:

Any idea what could be causing this? :<
Edited to add a link to the blend file:
My file.

Looks like an issue with either the normal map or possibly with ambient occlusion, could be that the normal map isn't set up properly in the shader nodes?

I would also suspect a problem with the normal map. It seems to be an issue in the skin material, would you mind adding a screenshot of the shader nodetree as well?

as you can see in the comments: we can just guess. If you really wanna have an answer, pls provide blend file. thx.

Could it be that there are not two objects in the same place (which you were able to rule out by deactivating the one object in render) but two meshes in Edit Mode? One that's perhaps accidentally hidden with H so it does not show in Edit Mode? Have you tried Alt+H to unhide everything? In Edit Mode, not Object Mode. If all the suggestions so far do not help, I agree with @Chris that we need the file.

Hello, Nick, please share a failing chunk of your mesh in a stripped-down .blend  on https://blend-exchange.com/ .. IMO, that would make clearing this up much quicker.
